# How to return value of the method from a different class to the output label

Tags: c#, asp.net, class, methods

I have a method created in class1 called method1.
Im trying to display method1 in a label object. Hopefully I described this properly. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.
Here is my class Ticket User.

```
    //property accessors
  public string CreateAccountMessage
    { get{
            return "Congratulations" + firstName + "Your account has been created. Your username is" + username;
        } set
        { CreateAccountMessage = value;
        }
    }
    //CreateAccount method
    public string CreateAccount()
    { return CreateAccountMessage;
    }}}
```

This is where i need to return CreateAccountMessage

```
    protected void btnCreateAccount_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lblsomelabel.Text = TicketUser. (this is where it only shows Equals and ReferenceEquals
    }
```

Comment: Let's see what you have tried.

Comment: i edited my post, hopefully i was clear. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok there are a few issues  - on the property set for `CreateAccountMessage`, `CreateAccountMessage = value` is setting the property, you almost certainly want a private variable and a full property here...read [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x9fsa0sw.aspx) for more info on properties

Though I think your real issue is that you are trying to access a static functions of the class TicketUser - when it should be a normal instance method call -

e.g. you should be able to do the following in code:

```
TicketUser user = new TicketUser ();
```

`user.`  (and then intellisense will kick in)

The fact you have no intellisense is because you are accessing the class directly (and its static methods, which don't match)  - you probably need to re-think your architecture - maybe passing the instance in as a field of a custom event arg

Comment: Thank you, The intellisense did kick in. It is giving me Error "Cannot convert method group 'CreateAccount' to non-delegate type 'string'. Did you intend to invoke the method? Im looking at the link you've posted and trying to figure out what i did wrong

Comment: I think i got it, I added (). lblCreateAccount.Text = user.CreateAccount();

Comment: glad you got it, don't know why you got a downvote for your question...gonna give you an upvote to compensate :)